# how to mock private static inner class?

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking

I have a class like

```
public class Enclosing {

   public String methodA() {
     Inner.getContext();
     ......
   }

   private static class Inner{
     // some context init
     public static Context getContext() {
       .....
     }
   }
}
```

Now I want to test methodA without invoking the real Inner.getContext(). I have been searching all over but cannot find a working solution. I am using Java 8. Can I have some help please? Many thanks

Comment: Inject the `inner` instance into `methodA` (I assume you meant `inner.getContext()`, or some other variable name); make `Inner` non-private.

Comment: getContext is the static method of Inner. I don't want to make Inner non-private. It is doing the context init that I really do NOT want to expose it

Answer (score 2):

You can apply the *extend and override technique*, here's how it works.

Given this code:

```
public class Enclosing {

   public String methodA() {
     Inner.getContext();
     ......
   }
```

You can move the `Inner.getContext()` call to a `protected` method:

```
public class Enclosing {

   public String methodA() {
     getContext();
     ......
   }

   protected void getContext() {
     Inner.getContext();
     ......
   }
```

And then in your test case, you can extend the enclosing class, and override the `protected` method to do whatever you want with it:

```
@Test
public void test_something() {
    Enclosing enclosing = new Enclosing() {
        @Override
        protected void getContext() {
            // do what you need here
        }
    };

    // your test code on enclosing where you control getContext
}
```

Comment: Thank you for replying. But I don't want to wrap Inner.getContext into some other method so it may be called by any other code. The reason I use this Inner.getContext() is because it is the thread-safe, while performant way to do runtime once/app only context initialization.

Comment: You can't have a cake and eat it too. If you want to test something that has a private initializer, you have no choice but expose it. How bad is a `protected` exposure? Or package local? Anything that's not public should not be called by user code. The risk involved in this technique is reasonably very small, and much smaller than not testing at all. It's up to you if you're still not convinced, but I still think this is your best and practical option.

Comment: @gigi2 sometimes you have to sacrifice encapsulation for testability. But the fact that the method is `protected`, combined with the fact that `getContext()` presumably doesn't do anything after the first init, makes this solution pretty safe. An alternative solution would be to move the method body to a (protected) `doMethodA()` and from `methodA()` call `Inner.getContext(); doMethodA();`. This will avoid exposing your initialization logic, but will somewhat expose an unsafe version of `methodA()`.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to @janos' answer, you can inject a *strategy* (basically, the "prefer composition over inheritance" approach):

```
interface ContextStrategy {
  void getContext();
}
```

and then inject an instance of this into the constructor of `Enclosing`:

```
class Enclosing {
  private final ContextStrategy ctxStrategy;

  Enclosing(ContextStrategy ctxStrategy) {
    this.ctxStrategy = ctxStrategy;
  }

  String methodA() {
    ctxStrategy.getContext();
    // ...
  }
}
```

and then implement this interface for the production case, as a nested class in `Enclosing`:

```
static class ContextStrategyImpl implements ContextStrategy {
  @Override public void getContext() {
    Inner.getContext();
  }
}
```

and implement an alternative version for your mock case.

Comment: Once you're making the class strategy-aware (as opposed to the inheritance approach in which the outer class is "unaware" of alternative initialization strategies), I would say it's cleaner to go with a simple boolean override switch, given OP's simple requirements.

Comment: @shmosel it is *kinda* unaware - one might argue that the lack of `final` on the class is saying that there might be alternative implementations of non-final methods in the class. But I see the point you are making, and agree that it may be simpler to use approaches other than the one I propose. On the other hand, I am not a fan of boolean switches ("what does true mean? what does false mean?" etc); a two-element enum might be better.

Comment: I agree that booleans are not always appropriate for any binary option, but I think a `doInit` field would convey its meaning pretty clearly in this case. In fact, if the switch was any more complex than a simple yes/no, I think the strategy approach would indeed be preferable.

Comment: Side note: with Java 8, you can make your solution a little more concise: `Enclosing() { this(Inner::getContext()); }`

Comment: thank you for the reply. I cannot do this though. The enclosing class is created by a framework and it requires a no-arg constructor

Answer (score 0):

You should *not* mock a `private` class (whether it is a nested class like the one here or an actual inner class).

Instead, mock only the `Context` type if it's really needed (otherwise, use a real `Context` object). For example, such a test is shown below, using the JMockit library:

```
@Test
public void mockingTheContext(@Mocked Context anyContext) {
    new Expectations() {{
      // record any method call results expected from "anyContext"
    }};

    new Enclosing().methodA();

    new Verifications() {{
      // verify calls to "anyContext", if applicable
    }};
}
```

In the test above, the fact that `Context` is created inside a nested class is irrelevant. In general, mocking `private` methods or classes should always be avoided, since they are only implementation details.

Comment: I tried that, with org.jmockit.jmockit:1.8. but the Inner.getContext() keeps getting called in my unit test. Can you be more specific?

Comment: `Inner.getContext()` wouldn't be mocked; only the `Context` class would, meaning any instance created with `new Context(...)` would get mocked. If `Context` is not a concrete class, though, `@Capturing` should be used instead of `@Mocked`.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. But I don't want to trigger Inner.getContext() at all. it is calling real context initialization, which I want to skip in this unit test. is it possible to do with jmockit?

Comment: It can be done with `new MockUp(class object for Inner.class)`. But does the `Inner#getContext()` method really executes some code that *must* be avoided? Maybe the question could add more information so I could improve this answer.

Comment: yes. Inner.getContext() is supposed to be executed in the cloud, copying some files, then setting up application context based on those files. I don't want to execute it at all in my unit test env. The reason I am using this Inner.getContext() is I have to do lazy context initialization at runtime, based on some input for methodA().